# Function (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced-- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++

Main program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "AdjacencyMatrix.h"

void Prim(Matrix*, int*, int);
int minVertex(Matrix*, int*);

int main() {
    Matrix M(6);
    int weight = 0;
    Prim(M,weight,0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void Prim(Matrix*G, int*D, int s) { // Prim’s MST algorithm
int VISITED = 1;
int UNVISITED = 0;
int V[6];                 // Store closest vertex
int i, w;
for (int i=0; i<G->n(); i++)       // Initialize
    D[i] = INFINITY;
D[s] = 0;
for (i=0; i<G->n(); i++) {         // Process the vertices
    int v = minVertex(G, D);
    G->setMark(v, VISITED);
    //if (v != s)
    //  AddEdgetoMST(V[v], v);         // Add edge to MST
    if (D[v] == INFINITY) return;    // Unreachable vertices
    for (w=G->first(v); w<G->n(); w = G->next(v,w))
        if (D[w] > G->weight(v,w)) {
            D[w] = G->weight(v,w);       // Update distance
            V[w] = v;                    // Where it came from
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Matrix class with its constructors and destructors:

```
#pragma once
#include <assert.h>
#include "GraphADT.h"

class Matrix : public Graph {
private:
    int numVertex, numEdge; // Store number of vertices, edges
    int**matrix;           // Pointer to adjacency matrix
    int*mark;              // Pointer to mark array
    int VISITED = 1;
    int UNVISITED = 0;
public:
    Matrix (int numVert) { Init(numVert); } 
    ~Matrix() {       // Destructor
        delete [] mark; // Return dynamically allocated memory
        for (int i=0; i<numVertex; i++)
            delete [] matrix[i];
        delete [] matrix;
    void Init(int n) { // Initialize the graph
        int i;
        numVertex = n;
        numEdge = 0;
        mark = new int[n];     // Initialize mark array
        for (i=0; i<numVertex; i++)
            mark[i] = UNVISITED;
        matrix = (int**) new int*[numVertex]; // Make matrix
        for (i=0; i<numVertex; i++)
            matrix[i] = new int[numVertex];
        for (i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)  // Initialize to 0 weights
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertex; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }

    int n() { return numVertex; } // Number of vertices
    int e() { return numEdge; }   // Number of edges

    // Return first neighbor of "v"
    int first(int v) {
        for (int i=0; i<numVertex; i++)
            if (matrix[v][i] != 0) return i;
        return numVertex;           // Return n if none
    }

    // Return v’s next neighbor after w
    int next(int v, int w) {
        for(int i=w+1; i<numVertex; i++)
            if (matrix[v][i] != 0)
                return i;
        return numVertex;           // Return n if none
    }
    // Set edge(v1, v2) to "wt"
    void setEdge(int v1, int v2, int wt) { 
        assert(wt>0, "Illegal weight value"); 
        if (matrix[v1][v2] == 0) numEdge++;
        matrix[v1][v2] = wt; 
    }

    void delEdge(int v1, int v2) { // Delete edge (v1, v2)
        if (matrix[v1][v2] != 0) numEdge--;
        matrix[v1][v2] = 0;
    }

    bool isEdge(int i, int j) // Is (i, j) an edge?
    { return matrix[i][j] != 0; }

    int weight(int v1, int v2) { return matrix[v1][v2]; }
    int getMark(int v) { return mark[v]; }
    void setMark(int v, int val) { mark[v] = val; }
    }
```

Here is the essential parts of `Graph` that I overlooked:

```
class Graph {
private:
    void operator =(const Graph&) {}    // Protect assignment
    Graph(const Graph&) {}         // Protect copy constructor
}
```

The rest of `Graph` is pure virtual functions.

I am receiving this error on the line that calls the `Prim` function.

The full error is `function "Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`.

I have been looking around for an answer but I can not seem to understand what I can do to fix this error. I think it has something to do with the constructors and destructors, but I do not know how to fix the issue.

I would also greatly appreciate any insight as to why this issue is occurring to prevent issues in the future.

Also, the Prim algorithm is straight from my textbook, it is not original code.

Edit: To include the full Matrix class for clarification.

Comment: There are multiple problems with the shown code that make it impossible for anyone to help you. For starters, the declaration of `Prim` does not match its definition. Furthermore, the compilation error is due to some class member of either the `Matrix` or `Graph` class, neither of which is shown. Until your code example meets all requirements of a [mcve] as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], it's pretty much impossible for anyone to tell you where the problem is.

Comment: You declare `Prim` as taking `Matrix` by value, which requires it to be copied. Some part of the class, not shown here, makes `Matrix` not copyable. That's what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Edited to include full `Matrix` class. This class implementation is also pulled from my textbook.

Comment: This can't be all. The implementation mentions names like `mark` and `matrix` whose declarations are not shown. Nor is class `Graph`; if that is non-copyable, so would be `Matrix`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Very sorry about that, I added all that I think you will need to see the full issue. I noticed the `protect` stuff at the top of `Graph`. This file is also from the text. Would that be the cause of the error?

Comment: Yes - by making `Graph`'s copy constructor and copy assignment operator private, the class is explicitly made non-copyable. Any class derived from it would also be non-copyable by default, unless it provides its own explicit copy constructor and copy assignment operator (that avoid copying `Graph` subobject). This is a strong hint that you should **not** be passing `Matrix` by value in the first place.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so I should instead create a pointer to the address of a class object and pass that into `Prim` instead?

Answer (score 2):

After some guidance from @IgorTandetnik, I realized that I need to pass in the class objects to the function in a way other than by value.

To do this, I changed

```
Matrix M(6);
int weights = 0;
```

to the following

```
    Matrix m1(6);
    Matrix* M;
    M = &m1;
    int weights = 0;
    int* w;
    w = &weights;
```

and also changed the function call to `Prim` to

```
Prim(M,w,0);
```

This in fact did solve the original problem. There are still errors in the code causing the stack to be corrupted around `weights` and `m1`, but since the original issue was solved, the question is answered.

Edit: As the comment below by Ben has said, my problem was that `Prim` is trying to fill an array of weights. To fix this, I changed the weight declaration to `int w[size]`, size being the number of vertices.

Comment: Your new problem is that `Prim` tries to fill in an array of weights, but you have passed a pointer to only one.